# Pandas apply(pd.Series), causing warnings "The default dtype for empty Series will be 'object' instead of 'float64'"

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Pandas apply(pd.Series), causing warnings "The default dtype for empty Series will be 'object' instead of 'float64' in a future version. Specify a dtype explicitly to silence this warning."

I'm trying to split the column of dictionaries in the dataframe with:`df['A'].apply(pd.Series)`, and then concat it with:`df=pd.concat([df.drop(['A'], axis=1), df['A'].apply(pd.Series)], axis=1)`, but it is possible that the dictionary in that column is empty. If it is in fact empty i get this warnings: `FutureWarning: The default dtype for empty Series will be 'object' instead of 'float64' in a future version. Specify a dtype explicitly to silence this warning.` The next thing that i tried to do was adding the dtype to the "pd.Series" like `df['A'].apply.pd.Series(dtype=float)` but it's causing the next error:    `raise ValueError("No objects to concatenate") ValueError: No objects to concatenate`.
What can i do to get rid of the warning messages?

Comment: Use `pd.json_normalize(df['A'])`